# Booting linux from USB flash drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb-drive

I have a lenovo desktop and a lenovo laptop, both running windows 8.1.

I downloaded the ubuntu 14.10 iso file, burnt it to a installation CD. Then install it on my desktop harddisk. Everything alright.

Then, using my desktop, I also install the OS on a 32G usb flash drive. I tired to boot my desktop from the usb flash drive, and it works.

However, when I tried to use the usb flash drive to boot my laptop. It failed. The result is a blank screen with no response at all that I need to restart my laptop.

Is it suppose to be so? I mean I installed Linux onto a usb flash drive using my desktop, then that usb is supposed to be able to boot my desktop only, but not other device?

Thanks in advance for your answer. Best regards!

Remark: The OS in the usb is a regular full installation, not a liveUSB.

Answer (score 1):

Does it even get to the grub bootloader screen?

If not then it is not even seeing the flash as a bootable device.  Maybe check the BIOS to make sure it is set to boot from USB as a first choice.  It could also be that the BIOS is unable to handle a 32G USB drive.  You could try with a smaller one to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not the normal behavior. An installed Ubuntu boots a generic kernel which is not coupled with the hardware you installed it on in the first place. therefore, I assume you will get the same behavior on your laptop when booting the installation cd instead of the installed Ubuntu.